# Understanding aide.db

Tags: permissions, aide

Aide (the file integrity monitor) creates a database called aide.db. In this file, two particular columns are attr and perms. How can the data in these columns be interpreted?

Answer (score 2):

In answer to my own question, experiments show the following.

aide.db (and aide.db.new) always has the following columns:

1. name - the name of the file / directory / soft link
2. lname - the target of the soft link, but "0" if this is not a soft link
3. attr - see below
4. perm - the permissions for this item - see below
5. inode - the inode for this item

There may be more columns, according to what you have requested in the configuration file(s).

The permissions may start with:

- 4: this is a directory
- 10: this is a file
- 12: this is a soft link

(Note that 'd' is the 4th letter of the alphabet, and 'l' is the 12th. But 'f' is not the 10th.)

The next digit is the setuid / setgid / sticky bits, and the last three digits are the usual permissions. For example, if the entry is 100755, this is a file with permissions rwxr-xr-x

The attributes column (attr) has bits which indicate what you have requested or what has been provided. Here are some of the bits, expressed in hex:

- 1: always set to 1
- 2: (I don't know)
- 4: p = perms
- 8: u = userid
- 10: g = groupid
- 20: s = size
- 40: a = atime   (I don't yet know how to read the times.)
- 80: c = ctime
- 100: m = mtime
- 200: i = inode
- 400: b = block count
- 800: n = number of links
- 4,000,000: S = growing size
- 8,000,000: I = ignore changed file name

All of those from 4 to 800 cause an extra column to be printed.

The following are for checksums. Checksums are only calculated for files, not for directories and not for soft links. The corresponding bit is set to 1 only for files.

- 1000: md5
- 2000: sha1
- 4000: rmd160
- 8000: tiger
- 10000: crc32
- 20000: haval
- 40,000,000: sha256
- 80,000,000: sha512

I am sure more could be discovered by looking at the source code. Please correct any mistakes.

Comment: Correction: All those from 8 to 800 . . .